# Flask + uwsgi + keras error " DAMN ! worker 1 （pid: 5240）died, killed by signal 11:（trying respawn……）"

Tags: python, flask, keras, uwsgi

I encountered a problem when I run `flask uwsgi` to call keras (using tensorflow backend) object detection API, an error “DAMN ! worker 1 （pid: 5240）died, killed by signal 11:（trying respawn……）” is reported. Then I try to use only one thread, but it doesn't work. Instead, another error occurs which is " !!!uWSGI process 347 got Segmentation Fault!!!". Could anyone give me some help? Thanks very much

The following is my configuration file:

```
[uwsgi]
module = img_recognize_demo_3:app
protocol = http
master = true

processess = 2
threads = 2
chdir = /media/xiu/新加卷/FlasklrProj

thunder-lock=true

http-socket = 0.0.0.0:5000
logto = /media/xiu/新加卷/FlasklrProj/img_demo.log
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
```

And this is the error in my log file:

```
*** Operational MODE: threaded ***
Using TensorFlow backend.
设置tensorflow后台： 
2018-11-05 15:39:05.848219: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2018-11-05 15:39:05.848850: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1524] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Ellesmere [Radeon Pro WX 7100]
AMDGPU ISA: gfx803
memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.243
pciBusID 0000:02:00.0
Total memory: 8.00GiB
Free memory: 7.75GiB
2018-11-05 15:39:05.848918: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1635] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-11-05 15:39:05.848975: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1044] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-11-05 15:39:05.849021: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1050]      0 
2018-11-05 15:39:05.849068: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1063] 0:   N 
2018-11-05 15:39:05.849139: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1183] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 7539 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Ellesmere [Radeon Pro WX 7100], pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0)
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 9 seconds on interpreter 0x559665933a40 pid: 10593 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 10593)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 10662, cores: 2)
[pid: 10662|app: 0|req: 1/1] 127.0.0.1 () {32 vars in 817 bytes} [Mon Nov  5 15:39:14 2018] GET /demo/config?data_dir=/media/xiu/%E6%96%B0%E5%8A%A0%E5%8D%B7/upload/testImg&save_dir=/media/xiu/%E6%96%B0%E5%8A%A0%E5%8D%B7/upload/testout2&if_object=1 => generated 237 bytes in 2 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 72 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
开始调用物体检测函数
读取待检测图片， 执行模型预测 /media/xiu/新加卷/upload/testImg/69c732e4gy1fuw8eljyssj20u00u0gn3.jpg
DAMN ! worker 1 (pid: 10662) died, killed by signal 11 :( trying respawn ...
Respawned uWSGI worker 1 (new pid: 10739)
[deadlock-detector] a process holding a robust mutex died. recovering...
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, I suggest you paste your code to your post as **text**  ( `code` ) and not as an **image**

Comment: Are you able to do that upload using the Flask dev server?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I solved the problem by changing threads=1, which is really work

Answer (score 0):

So far, upping `threads` from 1 to 4 seems to have helped for me.